# Entity Framework 6.1.1 - Programmatically set ID when StoreGenerated is Identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am at the early stages of building a new application. I am using EF6.1.1, most of my tables have a uniqueidentifier column and I have set StoreGenerated = Identity.

When I create new records they are  assigned a new Guid and it all works fine.

For testing/debugging purposes I have written code to write some of the tables to an XML file. When I import this file EF still generates a new Guid.

In this case only I don’t want EF to do generate a new Guid. I want to preserve the original Guids as not doing so would break foreign keys. I have set StoreGenerated = None and this solves the problem but it seems very inelegant and it would require me to manually create all the Guids.

I need to persuade EF to let me set the Guid in this one case. Is there a way to change the StoreGenerated property at runtime?

Comment: Just for the record, EF does not generate a new Guid when you specify that they are `StoreGenerated` or `DatabaseGenerated` using Identity. It is the store or the database that generates the identity (there's a clue in the name of the attribute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the `StoreGenerated` property value at runtime (or - in fact - any EF metadata). You need to decide whether you want to insert your keys or have database generate them and EF will play accordingly. GUIDs are kind of easy because even if you generate keys on the client you don't have to expose it - for instance you can always assign a key value in the constructor and have EF overwrite it for entities it materializes from the database. You could even make the key setter private to not let anyone else set the value.

Comment: I have done as you suggested and I now set the GUIDs in code. It all seems to work fine - Thank you for your help.